# optional type 'Bool' cannot be used as a boolean; Test for '!=nil' instead

Tags: swift, option-type

> optional type 'Bool' cannot be used as a boolean; Test for '!=nil' instead

[image]

I got an error at first **if**, by replacing the if condition (`after`), the *second if condition* did never run. Any idea?

#### Before:

```
if(userEmail?.isEmpty || userPassword?.isEmpty || userRepeatPassword?.isEmpty){
      displayMyAlertMessage("All fields are required")
      return
}

if(userPassword != userRepeatPassword){
      displayMyAlertMessage("Passwords do not match.")
}
```

#### After:

```
if(userEmail != nil || userPassword != nil || userRepeatPassword != nil){
      displayMyAlertMessage("All fields are required")
      return
}

if(userPassword != userRepeatPassword){
      displayMyAlertMessage("Passwords do not match.")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking if the value is different of nil and returning if it is, based un your comments and your second if you probably want to check if it is nil.

```
println("Checking login details")
if(userEmail.isEmpty || userPassword.isEmpty || userRepeatPassword.isEmpty){
      displayMyAlertMessage("All fields are required")
      println("Fail to login not all fields where fill") 
      return
} else if(userPassword != userRepeatPassword){
      displayMyAlertMessage("Passwords do not match.")
      println("Fail to login password does not match") 
} else {  
  var uiAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Registration was successful", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
  self.presentViewController(uiAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  uiAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { action in
   dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)
  }))
}
```

Comment: I tried this also, but the page will jump to another page, without doing anything

Comment: @GhasemTabatabaei I added a println to help debug. can you tell us what is been printed in your console?

Comment: User Login and Registration[9356:1301655] Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<UIAlertController: 0x7fc07a746540>)

Comment: @GhasemTabatabaei What are userEmail, userPassword, userRepeatPassword and userRepeatPassword? Are they Strings or UITextField?

Comment: I added a picture for more help.

Comment: @GhasemTabatabaei your problem is that you are creating a UIAlertController and dismissing the UIViewController at the same time, change the dismissViewController to the completion handler of the OK button of your Alert message

Comment: I still have some problem, but the 'Justin' code in some part worked for me. I will try again, and inform you (and review the rate). Thanks for your time

Comment: @GhasemTabatabaei it worked because you are not presenting the alert view anymore like before

Comment: @GhasemTabatabaei I update the answer to match your original design, show the alert and dismiss the modal after the user click ok, be carefull push a view on top another without dismiss as you can have an stackoverflow. I hope that help and good luck with your app!

Comment: everything worked perfectly, except the first IF CONDITION will never check. even with Justin's Code. If I don't enter anything in the fields I will get the "Registration was successful". which means, at first it should say "All fields are required".. something is wrong with if(something == nil) I guess..!?

Comment: @GhasemTabatabaei I just see the rest of your code it should not be nil but just a empty string "" i fix the answer it should work now

Comment: You are awesome dude. I do really appreciated for your help and time. my problem is solved. Thanks

Comment: @GhasemTabatabaei I always learn something new helping other people too! Glad is all working now! Good luck finishing your app!

Answer (score 5):

you need to wrapped it with `!` instead of `?`.
That will solved the error message:

```
if (username!.isEmpty) .....
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if(userEmail!.isEmpty || userPassword!.isEmpty || userRepeatPassword!.isEmpty)
```

You can't check the value of an optional since , you probably already know, *being an optional implies it can or cannot be there*. One solution is called `force unwrapping` and it is being done by using an "!" ( exclamation mark ). "?" ( question mark ) just lets the compiler know there *may be or may not be* a value so using the "!" we tell the compiler we know *it may or it may not be* a value inside that variable BUT *we know there will be one, even if it's an EMPTY STRING*, unlike other programming languages that consider empty strings, or empty arrays like "false". That's not the case in swift.

Your expression inside a conditional statement *MUST* be a valid boolean result.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: I was in a hurry, so I had to either post it as it is or close the browser.

Comment: @edduvs I was looking for the difference of "?" and "!". Was so helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @GhasemTabatabaei glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

With optional booleans, it works a little differently, you need to check explicitly if the value is nil. So that is exactly why your `After:` works and not your `Before:`

```
//now this is checking if your values are nil (empty) rather than not nil
//before if a user had valid fields, it would say that "All fields are required"
//now, this will work
if(userEmail == nil || userPassword == nil || userRepeatPassword == nil){
  displayMyAlertMessage("All fields are required")
} else if(userPassword != userRepeatPassword){
  displayMyAlertMessage("Passwords do not match.")
} else {
  //success
  //perform segue here to correct screen
}
```

There are a couple of options of how you can perform a segue, I will choose to use the `presentViewController` method, see below on how to integrate that. 
...

```
else {
  //success
  //perform segue here to correct screen
  presentViewController(yourMainScreenViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

You could also use the 
    performSegueWithIdentifier("yourMainScreenIdentifier", sender: nil) if you don't use the `presentViewController` method, like:

```
else {
  //success
  //perform segue here to correct screen
  performSegueWithIdentifier("yourMainScreenIdentifier", sender: nil)
}
```

I will add in what I assume your `displayMyAlertMessage` is:

```
func displayMyAlertMessage(alert: String) {
  println(alert)
}
```

Comment: I tried this also, but the page will jump to another page, without doing anything! Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by jumping to another page? Can you share some more of your code that is jumping to the other page? @GhasemTabatabaei

Comment: I meant, from Registration Page will jump back to the previous page (login) ..  (please see the picture I just added now).

Comment: See my code above, I have edited it, I think what you're going to want to do is perform a segue programmatically, and add and `else` statement so that if the user has successfully entered credentials, it does that segue to the main screen. @GhasemTabatabaei